# Built apk results in white screen and title

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, build, apk

Finally finished a project in Unity, and have been trying to build it. It hasn't been easy.

First off, building the APK on the computer and sending it over to install manually 'works', for a certain value of the word anyway. Attempting to run it instantly leads to [this kind of screen](https://i.redd.it/w6eyzr4ty9221.png).

So I did the only reasonable thing and tried to USB debug it via Android Studio. It was not amused:

```
    12/04 17:52:33: Launching Toothy
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\user\ApkProjects\Toothy\Toothy.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.company.toothygame
$ adb shell am start -n "com.company.toothygame/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.company.toothygame
Connecting to com.company.toothygame
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Error while starting native debug session: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Has anyone ever seen such a behavior? My google-fu has been failing me, owing to the lack of keywords the issue lends itself to.

EDIT: As requested, manifest.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.ads": "2.0.8",
    "com.unity.analytics": "2.0.16",
    "com.unity.package-manager-ui": "1.9.11",
    "com.unity.purchasing": "2.0.3",
    "com.unity.textmeshpro": "1.2.4",
    "com.unity.modules.ai": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.animation": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.assetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.audio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.cloth": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.director": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imageconversion": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imgui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.jsonserialize": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.particlesystem": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics2d": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.screencapture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrain": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrainphysics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.tilemap": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.ui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.uielements": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.umbra": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unityanalytics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vehicles": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.video": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vr": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.wind": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.xr": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file ?

Comment: do you use any kind of ads?

Comment: I'll add the manifest above, for formatting.

Yea, adds are used.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya checking out the game's resource usage shows it using a tiny amount of ram and no cpu. Probably relevant?